# /venues/suggestcompletion endpoint returns empty array

Tags: foursquare

We've been using the `/venues/suggestcompletion` endpoint for a while for our autocompletion feature for a while now.

It started returning empty arrays for all our queries recently.

Here is a sample set of GET parameters:

`{
    limit = 20;
    ll = "52.485799,13.437771";
    query = ostba;
}`

resulting in this URL:

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/suggestcompletion?client_id=OUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=OUR_CLIENT_SECRET&v=20120801&query=ostba&ll=52.485799,13.437771`

and corresponding output:

`meta =     {
        code = 200;
    };
    response =     {
        minivenues =         (
        );
    };`

I know `/venues/suggestcompletion` is meant as experimental but I couldn't find a notice of an API change. This is breaking the venue search functionality for our app in production. We'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks a lot…

Comment: We are also seeing this. Using their API explorer you can verify that it works, although they are using a oauth token instead of a client ID/secret like us. https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/suggestCompletion%3Fll%3D37.77,-77.48%26query%3Dford

Comment: The same situation there. Only user authenticated queries are answered.

Comment: We just switched to using the `/venues/search` endpoint. It is basically the same just that it returns more venue detail then we need, and when used in a live search box can be slower. But at least its not experimental and works.

Comment: This appears to be an issue that cropped up recently with the API. We are currently investigating why userless requests to this endpoint aren't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a temporary bug that was introduced yesterday. We believe we've fixed the problem -- sorry for that!